# How to remove some html from an element and append that new html in another place on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove some html from an element and insert that html into a new spot on the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/QtaDg/

My attempts (commented out) aren't working.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li class="bye">Bye</li>    
</ul>

<div id="new-html"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('ul').find('.bye').remove().appendTo('new-html');
```

or

```
$('ul').find('.bye').remove().clone().appendTo('new-html');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot the # in `#new-html`

```
$('ul').find('.bye').remove().appendTo('#new-html');
```

Also, appending an element automatically removes it from where it was, so there is no need to remove it

```
$('ul').find('.bye').appendTo('#new-html');
```

Comment: Thanks, stupid mistake on my part. This is actually what I needed: `$('ul').find('.bye').remove().end().appendTo('#new-html');` I wanted the non removed part to be in the new div.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$('ul').find('.bye').appendTo('#new-html');
```

There's no need to remove the element first. And `#` is used in the selector by id.

Also note that appending an `<li>` element into a `<div>` will lead to invalid HTML.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/KHMWR/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code was almost correct, but you wanted to use the correct CSS selector for `new-html`, `#new-html`. However, you should also use jQuery's [detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/), as it will preserve any data associated with the element. So, use this:

`$('ul').find('.bye').detach().appendTo('new-html');`

And fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/QtaDg/1/

Comment: Keeping handlers when moving nodes is dangerous practice since handlers are often sensitive to the location of the node. Don't do it blindly, therefore, don't offer that as advice any time you're moving a node.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with you, if I'm moving a node, I would expect it to take any bound information along with it. I would do a lot more hair pulling trying to figure out why this data I had added two lines above was no longer attached to the element than the handler traversing the DOM incorrectly.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what `detach` does, it doesn't seem to be needed to keep handlers, or to keep `$.data()` values.  http://jsfiddle.net/QtaDg/4/